# code "Request.Headers.Range" not working on asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

```c#
RangeHeaderValue rangeHeader = base.Request.Headers.Range;
```

above codes are working on asp.net web api, however it is not working on asp.net core. Is there an altnative in asp.net core for getting RangeHeaderValue?

Answer (score 0):

Range Request are not supported in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3702). Therefore some own code for handling range requests is needed. For getting the Range-Header in the mentioned issue the tip is given, that you can import the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions` package and use `httpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().Range`